# Unzip a folder in Android with sub folders

Tags: java, android, unzip

Firstly I have googled this many times and searched a huge bunch of Stackoverflow pages but I can't get anything to work. What I am trying to do is I have a zip file with a structure like:

zipfile.zip

> Folder
>
> > Subfolder1
> >
> > > Sub Folder With Spaces (about 100 but the amount will not be known of these)
> > >
> > > > Sub Sub Folder With spaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few files
> > > >
> > > > SubSubFolderWithoutSpaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few more files
> >
> > Subfolder2
> >
> > > Sub Folder With Spaces (about 100 but the amount will not be known of these)
> > >
> > > > Sub Sub Folder With spaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few files
> > > >
> > > > SubSubFolderWithoutSpaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few more files
> >
> > Subfolder3
> >
> > > Sub Folder With Spaces (about 100 but the amount will not be known of these)
> > >
> > > > Sub Sub Folder With spaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few files
> > > >
> > > > SubSubFolderWithoutSpaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few more files
> >
> > Subfolder4
> >
> > > Sub Folder With Spaces (about 100 but the amount will not be known of these)
> > >
> > > > Sub Sub Folder With spaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few files
> > > >
> > > > SubSubFolderWithoutSpaces
> > > >
> > > > > A few more files

I am currently using the code from http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29 to try and unzip the file yet all it does is create a directory called for example zipfile and then have a sub directory in it called folder which has nothing inside the directory which obviously should not be happening.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Oh and in case you are wondering I do have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this help you:

```
private boolean unzipPack(InputStream stream) {
    FileOutputStream out;
    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
    try {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(stream);
        ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                File newDir = new File(rootDirectory + entry.getName());
                newDir.mkdir();
            } else {
                String name = entry.getName();
                File outputFile = new File(rootDirectory + name);
                String outputPath = outputFile.getCanonicalPath();
                name = outputPath
                .substring(outputPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                outputPath = outputPath.substring(0, outputPath
                .lastIndexOf("/"));
                File outputDir = new File(outputPath);
                outputDir.mkdirs();
                outputFile = new File(outputPath, name);
                outputFile.createNewFile();
                out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                int numread = 0;
                do {
                    numread = zis.read(buf);
                    if (numread <= 0) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                    }
                } while (true);
                out.close();
            }
            entry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Reference**:
`android pico installer source`

Comment: @NStorm What is your problem?